How to inject a React component inside static pre-rendered HTML coming from the database in Next.js?
I have some pre-rendered HTML on my server coming from a Markup conversion that I don't want to do each time.
I know how to inject that into the page with dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but now I also want to sprinkle some React components inside that HTML.
I also managed to convert a component to a string and inject that into the HTML with:
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

and then using an HTML parser such as node-html-parser to find the correct insertion place as per: How to use DOMParser in next.js?
So the last missing thing is that I want to properly hydrate that injected components such that JavaScript effects will be active. In the example below, that means I want to be able to click a simple injected counter and have its count go up as expected.
This is as far as I've gotten:
pages/index.js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

import { parse } from 'node-html-parser'

function Counter({ initialCount }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount)
  return <button
    onClick={() => setCount(i => i+1)}>Click me! {count}</button>
}

const SERVER_HTML_SELECTOR = '.second'

export default function IndexPage({ initialCount, serverHtml }) {
  const serverHtmlElem = parse(serverHtml)
  const clientHtmlElem = useRef(null)
  serverHtmlElem.querySelector(SERVER_HTML_SELECTOR).innerHTML = renderToString(<Counter {...{ initialCount }} />)
  useEffect(() => {
    clientHtmlElem.current
    if (clientHtmlElem.current) {
      console.log(initialCount)
      hydrateRoot(
        clientHtmlElem.current.querySelector(SERVER_HTML_SELECTOR),
        <Counter {...{ initialCount }} />
      )
    }
  }, [initialCount, serverHtml])
  return <div>
    <div>Direct from React</div>
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: serverHtmlElem.outerHTML }}
      ref={clientHtmlElem}
    />
  </div>
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params = {}, req, res }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      // This would be dynamically fetched from the database in the actual usage.
      initialCount: 10,
      serverHtml: `<div>
<div class="first">I'm filled</div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third">I'm also filled</div>
</div>
`,
    }
  }
}

but when I try it out I get several errors on the browser:

Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.


Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Click me! 10" Client: "Click me! "


Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <div>.

What am I doing wrong?
package.json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --turbo",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "node-html-parser": "^6.1.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5"
  }
}

next.config.js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

.eslintrc
{
  "extends": "next",
  "root": true
}

and then I run with:
npm install
npm run dev

Also asked at:

https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/1ewwea3/how_to_inject_a_react_component_inside_static/
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/69099

Related:

NextJS custom component hydration I think they're asking something similar, but it is hard to be sure because the example given is not a complete as mine
Render React component as static public HTML in next.js


The following approach seems to work without any warnings. It does produce a slight flicker on development mode due to reactStrictMode: true double useEffect shenanigans which is sad, but it's the best I've gotten so far. The flicker was not visible in production however. But it was visible in production on my more complex app, so it's not solved.
So instead of hydrating, I'm just creating my own independent DOM child node that I manage myself so React will stop complaining. https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs suggests this is allowed:

However, this doesn’t mean that you can’t do it at all. It requires caution. You can safely modify parts of the DOM that React has no reason to update. For example, if some  is always empty in the JSX, React won’t have a reason to touch its children list. Therefore, it is safe to manually add or remove elements there.

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

import { parse } from 'node-html-parser'

function Counter({ initialCount }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount)
  return <button
    onClick={() => setCount(i => i+1)}>Click me! {count}</button>
}

const SERVER_HTML_SELECTOR = '.second'

export default function IndexPage({ initialCount, serverHtml }) {
  const serverHtmlElem = parse(serverHtml)
  const clientHtmlElem = useRef(null)
  serverHtmlElem.querySelector(SERVER_HTML_SELECTOR).innerHTML = renderToString(<Counter {...{ initialCount }} />)
  useEffect(() => {
    clientHtmlElem.current
    if (clientHtmlElem.current) {
      const secondElem = clientHtmlElem.current.querySelector(SERVER_HTML_SELECTOR)
      const div = document.createElement('div')
      const root = createRoot(div)
      root.render(<Counter {...{ initialCount }} />)
      secondElem.replaceChildren(div)
      return () => {
        // Doesn't seem to make a difference. But why not? React tends to like when we leave DOM nodes unchanged.
        secondElem.replaceChildren()
      }
    }
  }, [initialCount])
  return <div>
    <div>Direct from React</div>
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: serverHtmlElem.outerHTML }}
      ref={clientHtmlElem}
    />
  </div>
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params = {}, req, res }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      // This would be dynamically fetched from the database in the actual usage.
      initialCount: 10,
      serverHtml: `<div>
<div class="first">I'm filled</div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third">I'm also filled</div>
</div>
`,
    }
  }
}

May the React Gods be with me.
